# Remove duplicates items from Hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, unique

I have the following array of hashes

```
input = [
  {'line_number' => 1, 'name' => 'Name1', 'value' => 'Value'},
  {'line_number' => 1, 'name' => 'Name2', 'value' => 'Value'},
  {'line_number' => 2, 'name' => 'AnotherName', 'value' => 'AnotherValue'}
]
```

I want, which after checking for uniqueness the output would be

```
output = [
  {'line_number' => 1, 'name' => 'Name2', 'value' => 'Value'},
  {'line_number' => 2, 'name' => 'AnotherName', 'value' => 'AnotherValue'}
]
```

because simple uniqueness

```
input.uniq! { |i| i['line_number'] }
```

give me

```
output = [
  {'line_number' => 1, 'name' => 'Name1', 'value' => 'Value'},
  {'line_number' => 2, 'name' => 'AnotherName', 'value' => 'AnotherValue'}
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the logic behind that? Keep the item that comes last or the one with larger value for `'name'`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the last one, you can do this

```
input.each_with_object({}) {|h, obj| obj[h['line_number']] = h}.values
# => [{"line_number"=>1, "name"=>"Name2", "value"=>"Value"},
# =>  {"line_number"=>2, "name"=>"AnotherName", "value"=>"AnotherValue"}]
```

Comment: Thank you Santhosh, that really helped me

Comment: My preference, so far. Consider a hash-like name as a replacement for `obj`. The latter sounds like it could be any kind of object, but we know it's a hash.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland, Both block arguments are Hashes, couldn't think of a name to differentiate the two.

Comment: I often use `h`, `g` and `f` for hashes (in that order). It may not help others read my code, but it tells me the object referenced is a hash. I suppose everyone has their own preferences for naming block variables.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange question, but, maybe, it can help you:

```
input.group_by { |i| i['line_number'] }.values.map! { |i| i.last }
```

Comment: or `.values.map(&:last)`

Comment: Yea, maybe the question a little bit strange.
Thank you too, your solution is also helped me.

Comment: @KhachaturSaribekyan did you see [my above comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37569312/remove-duplicates-items-from-ruby#comment62626255_37569312)? It would be helpful if you could clarify your question.

Comment: @Stefan I can't explain a whole problem, because it's hard to explain, but your written solution already helped me to fix the big problem that I had.

Comment: @KhachaturSaribekyan I'm just asking you to explain your logic for selecting the item. There are two items with a `line_number` of `1`. How do you decide which one to keep and which one to drop?

Comment: Do we know the order of elements of the values (arrays) of the hash produced by [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)? It is not specified in the doc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the last instead of the first one, why not simply

```
input.reverse.uniq { |i| i['line_number'] }
```

Comment: You have to add another `reverse` at the end.

Comment: Yeah, if the resulting order is important. That has not been specified.

Answer (score 0):

```
input.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g['line_number']=>g) }.values
  #=> [{"line_number"=>1, "name"=>"Name2", "value"=>"Value"},
  #    {"line_number"=>2, "name"=>"AnotherName", "value"=>"AnotherValue"}]
```